# Add A record into Datatable in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have a textInput box and I want to save the values of textinput  into the datatable in shiny R.The problem is that when I press Add button it only add empty record into dataTable. Moreover I get the following Error Message:

Error Message:

```
Warning in widgetFunc() :
  renderDataTable ignores ... arguments when expr yields a datatable object; see ?renderDataTable
```

The UI and server codes are as following: 
ui.r

```
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
helpText("Modify the Filterations Method To find 
The most Important KPI"),
#use shiny js to disable the ID field
shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
#DT::dataTableOutput("responses"),
shinyjs::disabled(textInput("id1", "Id", "0")),


    # Copy the line below to make a text input box
    textInput("name1", label = h3("Method's Name"),""),
    hr(),
    actionButton("submit1", "add"),
    hr(),
    # Delete button 
    actionButton(inputId = "delete1", label = "Delete", icon = icon("minus-circle"),class = "btn-primary"),
    #NEW button
    actionButton("new1", "Reset",icon = icon("refresh"),class = "btn-primary"),
    ),
     mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses2")
     )
     )
    ),
```

server.R

```
    # Define the fields we want to save from the form

     CreateDefaultRecord1 <- function() {
       mydefault <- CastData1(list(id = "0", name = ""))
       return (mydefault)
     }


     CastData1 <- function(data) {
       datar <- data.frame(name1 = data["name"], 
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

       rownames(datar) <- data["id"]
       return (datar)
     }

     UpdateInputs1 <- function(data, session) {
       updateTextInput(session, "id", value = unname(rownames(data)))
       updateTextInput(session, "name", value = unname(data["name"]))
     }

     GetNextId1 <- function() {
       if (exists("responses2") && nrow(responses2) > 0) {
         max(as.integer(rownames(responses2))) + 1
       } else {
         return (1)
       }
     }

     CreateData1 <- function(data) {

       data <- CastData1(data)
       rownames(data) <- GetNextId1()
       if (exists("responses2")) {
         responses2 <<- rbind(responses2, data)
       } else {
         responses2 <<- data
       }
     }

     ReadData1 <- function() {
       if (exists("responses2")) {
         responses2
       }
     }

     UpdateData1 <- function(data) {
       data <- CastData1(data)
       responses2[row.names(responses2) == row.names(data), ] <<- data
     }
     DeleteData1 <- function(data) {
       responses2 <<- responses2[row.names(responses2) != unname(data["id"]), ]
     }

     GetTableMetadata1 <- function() {
       fields <- c(id = "Id", 
                   name = "Name")

       result <- list(fields = fields)
       return (result)
     }
      formData1 <- reactive({
    sapply(names(GetTableMetadata1()$fields), function(x) input[[x]])
  })

  # Click "Submit" button -> save data
  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    if (input$id != "0") {
      UpdateData1(formData1())
    } else {
      CreateData1(formData1())
      UpdateInputs1(CreateDefaultRecord1(), session)
    }
  }, priority = 1)

  # Press "New" button -> display empty record
  observeEvent(input$new1, {
    UpdateInputs1(CreateDefaultRecord1(), session)
  })

  # Press "Delete" button -> delete from data
  observeEvent(input$delete1, {
    DeleteData1(formData1())
    UpdateInputs1(CreateDefaultRecord1(), session)
  }, priority = 1)

  # Select row in table -> show details in inputs
  observe({if (length(input$responses2_rows_selected) > 0) 
  { 
    data <- ReadData1()[input$responses2_rows_selected, ] 
    UpdateInputs1(data, session) }
  })

  # display table
  output$responses2 <- DT::renderDataTable({

    #update after submit is clicked
    input$submit1
    #update after delete is clicked
    input$delete1
    DT::datatable(ReadData1())

  }, server = FALSE, selection = "single",
  colnames = unname(GetTableMetadata1()$fields)[-1]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

in the server, I have to change the id of `name into name1`  and also change the id of `id into id1`.